# How do you get sorted data back from a DataBound gridview?

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

Here's the scenario I am trying to achieve. I have a DataGrid control on my form. I am using [XCeed Data Grid for .Net](http://xceed.com/Grid_WinForms_Intro.html) as my control of choice. I am driving the DataGrid via a DataTable as its DataSource. The Grid allows me to sort the data by column which is very cool. That same Data is also being plotted on a Chart control. This way you can see the data as a table AND a chart.

What I want to know is to be able to sort the data in the grid by clicking on a column and then see the new sorted data updated on the chart. Generally speaking, how would you go about doing something like that? How do you grab sorted data *back* from a gridview contorl? Extra points for telling me how it's done with XCeed Grid control :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

do the following on the sort event for the grid.. or whenever

```
        //get data w/ sort expression
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)gridview1.DataSource;

        //bind sorted data to another control
        chartcontrol.datasource = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
        chartcontrol.databind();

        //add sorted ids to session to get crazy with
        if (dt != null)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(dt.DefaultView[i]["ID"].ToString() + ",");
            }
            if (sb.Length > 0)
                sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);

            Session["SortedIDs"] = sb.ToString();
         }
```